# Are there named ranges (or similar facility) in the JS API for Word?

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I am writing an add-in for Word using the [JS API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/overview/word-add-ins-reference-overview).

My requirement is - do a search for a string, highlight the matching ranges (using font.highlightColor) - so far no problems.

But I also need to keep track of which ranges/texts have been highlighted, so that I can later programatically remove the highlights when the user clicks a button.

I have implemented similar functionality in a Google Docs Addon by using their [Named Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/named-range) feature. The range builder in that API lets you build a new range out of all the matching ranges, give it a name, and later find them by name.

How would I go about achieving this via the Word JS API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word and its JS API have no direct equivalent to a "Named Range".

Word has bookmarks, which can serve a similar purpose. These are not supported in the current JS API, but are [in beta](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.documentcreated?view=word-js-preview#getbookmarkrange-name-) for the API settings requirement 1.4.

Other than that, Word has ***[content controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.contentcontrol?view=word-js-preview)*** which *are* supported in the API set 1.1 (and later). This should be roughly equivalent as far as marking contiguous runs of text and later identifying them.